# How to convert a record of strings to floats in elm

Tags: elm

I have a record that is supplied by the user:

```
type alias Model =
  { age : String,
    weight : String,
    height : String,
    appetite : String
  }
```

I want to convert it to numbers:

```
type alias FloatModel =
  { age : Float,
    weight : Float,
    height : Float,
    appetite : Float
  }
```

My struggle is that `String.toFloat` might return `Nothing` if the user entered bad data. So I guess I want a `Maybe FloatModel` to handle bad data. How can I call `String.toFloat` on each member, and if they're all successful return `Just FloatModel` and if not return `Nothing`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to retain the integrity of `FloatModel`, so that all fields are `Float` values, you could have a function which takes a `Model` and returns a `Maybe FloatModel`, which succeeds only when all fields can be parsed.

This could be done by [mapping over each of the fields](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Maybe#map4), so that a single failure will "bubble up" and cause the function to return `Nothing`.

```
deserializeModel : Model -> Maybe FloatModel
deserializeModel { age, weight, height, appetite } =
    Maybe.map4 FloatModel
        (String.toFloat age)
        (String.toFloat weight)
        (String.toFloat height)
        (String.toFloat appetite)
```